# Image Feature Request

Tags: feature-request

I am a moderator for Woodworking SE and question/answer content often requires images. There is a problem loading images to StackExchange sites in that the size of the files must be less than 2 meg. Most photos these days are larger than that and the user must find a way to reduce the file size. This tends to discourage users from including photos and posts often end up including external links to dropbox or other sites rather than adding the photos. I end up chasing these links down and converting the photos myself to provide meaningful content in the posts that will survive over time. I realize that detail is lost in reducing the size, but 2 meg still allows for adequate information for the images I have reduced (using photshop).

It would be very helpful if the image dialog was able to reduce image sizes itself making it easier for people to post. I have seen this ability on other sites from time to time and would like to request this feature in SE.

Comment: @Sonic Strange that this post has a score of +3 and the older one -2.